# system argument out of range exception

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a report choosing start date and end date.

I tested at the office and it is working fine.

When it is installed at the user's place, the following error pops up.
[image]

I wonder why is that?

I bring back the database and run at the office.

Still working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not a parsing problem in `DateTime.Parse`, which is what I first expected. Your code (`Form1.Calculat`) is calling the constructor directly, so you should be able to log what values you're trying to use to create the `DateTime`, along with which row of the database is causing the problem.

We can't really do any of that diagnostic work for you, but once you've worked out what the values are, you should look through your code to work out where they're coming from.

Does your client have a different default culture to your development machine? That's normally the first port of call - but unless you're *manually* parsing date/time strings into their constituent bits, I wouldn't have particularly expected this failure mode.

If you could post some code, that would really help.

Comment: Actually, I already checked in the regional settings. The settings are the same.

Comment: @william: And have you added any diagnostics to find out what you're passing into the `DateTime` constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the values to the TimeToTicks method ? 
Probably these values are not forming a valid DateTime. Why it works on your office PC might be because you have different culture settings.

For example, in one culture "11/25/2010" is a valid date as the format (MM/dd/yyyy), but on a different culture, where date format is set as (dd/MM/yyyy) it will not be a valid date.

You can change the system date format from the control panel or modify your code accordingly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is most of a problem Culture specific rather than any other issue. At one system the date format would be MM/DD/YYYY and at other system it would DD/MM/YYYY or something like that. So the datetime object should be picked culture specific and values should be passed that way as well.

Hope it fixes the problem.